# webpack pick up changes in strange manner

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack-dev-server during development. If I change javasript file and press `ctrl+S` sometimes webpack starts rebuilding process, but sometimes he does nothing. I can't figure out why this happens. For example I add some code, press `ctrl+S` couple times and nothing happens, then I add some spaces, press `ctrl+S` and webpack starts rebuild. Why this happpens?

Comment: And the editor, system you use?

Comment: I am on windows 8.1 and Webstorm 2016.1